# Prevent 301 redirect to affect subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This code affect my subdomains as well.

```
Redirect 301 /some-adress /
```

For example "subdomain1.domain.com/some-adress" will redirect to "subdomain.domain.com/"

I only wanted to redirect "domain.com/some-adress" to "domain.com/". Not the subdomains. How can I prevent it from redirecting the subdomain?

Comment: Do all sub domains use same .htaccess file?

Comment: The subdomains directories are located in the public_html directory. So I belive they are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert that rule into `mod_rewrite` with a condition to allow this rule for main domain only.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^some-adress / [L,R=301]
```